# Call unmanaged function in struct from VTable

Tags: c#, .net, unmanaged, vtable

Is it possible to call functions from C#, to an unmanaged function in a struct (via VTable).

For example, I am in-process hooking an application, and I am re-creating the structs for each class (of the application).

```
public struct SomeStruct {
   [FieldOffset(0x00)]
   public IntPtr * VTable;

   [FieldOffset(0x10)]
   public uint SomeValue;
}
```

Then, I usually do:

```
var * data = (SomeStruct*)(Address);
```

And I wish to call a function from the VTable of the structure in either of the following ways

```
Invoke<delegate>(data->VTable[0x3C])(delegateArguments)
```

Or

```
var eax = Invoke<Func<uint,uint>(data->VTable[0x3C])(arg1,arg2)
```

Furthermore, could this be done efficiently (as these vtable funcs could be called numerous times)?

Perhaps via Reflection Emit?

From what I know, marshalling has to create the delegate function every time I call the `Invoke<>` func.

Comment: Is the pointer to the `VTable` field correct?  This is a pointer to a pointer, which in this case, seems redundant.

Comment: @casperOne I think it makes sense if you want to treat it as a pointer, so you can use `data.VTable[0x3C]` instead of `ReadIntPtr()` as you suggested.

Comment: @svick Just wanted to make sure that it was correctly being brought over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that a virtual method table contains pointers to functions, assuming you know the offset (which it appears you do) you can get the pointer value in an [`IntPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.aspx) by calling the [`ReadIntPtr` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0y7w59b) on the [Marshal class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asx0thw2), like so:

```
IntPtr ptr = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(data.VTable, 0x3C);
```

Then you can call the [`GetDelegateForFunctionPointer` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getdelegateforfunctionpointer.aspx) on the [`Marshal` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.aspx) to get a delegate of the appropriate type, like so:

```
// Assuming a signature of f(int, int) returning int
Func<int, int, int> func = (Func<int, int, int>)
    Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(ptr, typeof(Func<int, int, int>));
```

Then you can call the delegate as needed.

Comment: Yeah I seem to have come to the same conclusion (but I cache the functions, and i use a generic GetDelegateForFunctionPointer). That way, calling the func will not have that much of of a performance loss

Comment: @Dan No reason to not cache it, that address isn't going to shift at all for the life of the process that it's loaded in.

Comment: Yes, but casperOne, as I don't actually store a reference to the function it's self, I need a way to cache is so I don't keep calling the GetDelegateForFunctionPointer. Look at my answer at the "Select" function I made as a wrapper for the virtual Select function

Comment: @Dan I'm not sure I follow.  Cache strategies really have little to do with this problem; once you get the delegate, how you cache it (and if you really need to) is up to you.  The important part is getting the function from the vtable in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have found a possible solution:

I have created a generic Invoke method that creates and caches all delegates for future use
Also

```
 public void Select(uint target)
        {
            fixed (void* pThis = &this)
            {
                Generic.Invoke<Action<uint, uint>>(this.VTable[0xC0], CallingConvention.ThisCall)
                    ((uint)pThis, target);
            }
        }

        [FieldOffset(0x00)]
        public uint* VTable;
```

Caches:

```
  public static T Invoke<T>(uint addr, CallingConvention conv) where T : class
        {
          var type = typeof(T);
            if (!cache.Contains(type))
                cache.Set<T>(type, NativeHelper.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<T>(addr, conv));

            return cache.Get<T>(type);
        }
```

And the function that creates the function (and works for generic Func/Action)

```
public static T GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<T>(uint ptr, CallingConvention conv)
        where T : class
        {

            var delegateType = typeof(T);
            var method = delegateType.GetMethod("Invoke");
            var returnType = method.ReturnType;
            var paramTypes =
                method
                .GetParameters()
                .Select((x) => x.ParameterType)
                .ToArray();
            var invoke = new DynamicMethod("Invoke", returnType, paramTypes, typeof(Delegate));
            var il = invoke.GetILGenerator();
            for (int i = 0; i < paramTypes.Length; i++)
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg, i);
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, ptr);

            il.EmitCalli(OpCodes.Calli, conv, returnType, paramTypes);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
            return invoke.CreateDelegate(delegateType) as T;
        }
```